# How to write The values of Latitude, Longitude and another variable's values in a csv file in three different columns?

Tags: python, csv, latitude-longitude

I want to write The values of Latitude, Longitude and Air_flux values in a csv file in three different columns.

Here is the code in Python3 that I have done so far:
The file "path" has all the values of "Air_Flux" across specified Lat and Lon.

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

LAT_MIN = 34.675
LAT_MAX = 38.275
LON_MIN = 124.625
LON_MAX = 130.795
path = 'BESS_PAR_Daily.A2015004.nc_output.csv' # "File That contains the Values Of Air_Flux"

flux = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',') # Reading Data from File
latData = np.arange(LAT_MIN, LAT_MAX, 0.05)
lonData = np.arange(LON_MIN, LON_MAX, 0.05)


with open('data.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    for x in np.nditer(latData.T, order='C'):
        for y in np.nditer(lonData.T, order='C'):
        file.write(str(x))
        file.write("\n")

        file.write(str(y))
        file.write("\n")

    for fl in np.nditer(flux):
        file.write(str(fl))
        file.write("\n")

file.close()
```

I only know the way to store values in One column... 
BUT:
    I want to write The values of Latitude, Longitude and Air_flux values in a csv file in such a way that one column would have Latitude values, 2nd column for Longitude value and the third column for "Air_flux"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the values of flux are stored across those Lat and Lons, after iterating Lat values across Lon, I fetched the indices of lat and lon across flux:

```
writer.writerow([x, y, flux[lat.index, lon.index]])
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you're data is required in the format

```
LAT1 LON1 FLUX1
LAT2 LON2 FLUX2
```

In that case you don't need multiple for loops, you can pass all three arrays to the `nditer` method and then use `csvwriter.writerows` to write all values in a stretch.

Here is an example based on your scenario

```
import numpy as np
import csv

LAT_MIN = 34.675
LAT_MAX = 38.275
LON_MIN = 124.625
LON_MAX = 130.795
# path = 'BESS_PAR_Daily.A2015004.nc_output.csv' # "File That contains the Values Of Air_Flux"

# flux = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',') # Reading Data from File
# latData = np.arange(LAT_MIN, LAT_MAX, 0.05)
# lonData = np.arange(LON_MIN, LON_MAX, 0.05)
flux = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
latData = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
lonData = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

with open('data.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    for x,y,z in np.nditer([latData.T, lonData.T, flux], order='C'):
        writer.writerow([x,y,z])
```

Also you don't need `file.close()` since the `with` block takes care of it

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. But I have to use All the values in Latitude and Longitude. First I read all the values of Lat across Lon and then along those Lat and Lon( the reason for nested for loop). The values of "Air Flux" is stored in the file named "Path" so I have to do it the way I did. My arrays (Lat & Lon)  have different dimensions(73*124) so I have to read all the values of Lat across Lon..

Comment: @user11109061 one quick help. Can you update your question with a few sample values and the output you are expecting? It would be easier to visualize it that way

Comment: My output is like this:     Latitude     Longitude         Flux                                                                                                             
                                      34.675        124.625            24                                         
                                      34.675         124.675           20

Comment: @user11109061 I understand that you got it working. Feel free to accept (including yours)/upvote any solutions that you find useful

Comment: Yeah I aproved yours .. The last line of code definitely worked (writer.writerow([x,y,z])) : Thanks for that

Comment: @user11109061 good to know that helped. I see that you have approved your own answer, can you add a bit more context/surrounding code so its easy for people who take a look at it to try it out?